# Floor and Ceiling to specified int

Tags: c#, integer

This relates to [Round to specified int](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109319/round-to-specified-int) but I'm separating these methods out since they're technically different.

Is there a method that already performs a custom floor and ceiling to a specified integer?

```
// If the interval is 5, 9 --> 5.
public static int FloorTo(this int value, int interval)
{
    var remainder = value % interval;
    return remainder > 0 ? value - remainder : value; 
}

// If the interval is 5, 6 --> 10.
public static int CeilingTo(this int value, int interval)
{ 
    var remainder = value % interval;
    return remainder > 0 ? value + (interval - remainder) : value;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your methods take `int` parameters but it seems like you only have really thought about positive numbers. This yields some inconsistencies. For example:

   - `(-28).FloorTo(6) == -28`
   - `(-28).FloorTo(-6) == -28`
   - `(28).FloorTo(-6) == 24`

   For `CeilingTo` the results are:

   - `(-28).CeilingTo(6) == -28`
   - `(-28).CeilingTo(-6) == -28`
   - `(28).CeilingTo(-6) == 18`

   If you don't want to think about or deal with negative numbers you should either change the signature to accept only `uint` parameters (which would require the caller to think about what to do in case he's got an `int`) or you check and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception
2. Just considering positive numbers `FloorTo` could be changed to

   ```
   public static int FloorTo(this int value, int interval)
   {
      var remainder = value % interval;
      return value - remainder;
   }
   ```

   Less logic to read and verify in your head.